# Saving the values of hardware registers for a process during context switching

Tags: kernel, cpu, interrupt, cpu-registers, context-switching

Whenever an interrupt occurs, processor stores the current state in cpu registers.In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block , it is mentioned that when context switching occurs, kernel saves the contents of cpu or hardware registers for the interrupted process in the kernel.In one case, the current values of cpu registers are saved in the cpu itself and in the other case, it is saved in the kernel.Is it correct? Whether context switching is treated differently when compared to a normal interrupt? Ultimately it is also a form of interrupt... right ?

Comment: Context switching is context switching, a software operation implemented by the kernel. An interrupt is an interrupt, a hardware operation carried by the CPU. You didn't tag an architecture but in general upon an interrupt the CPU save the *minimal context*, in most cases just the PC,  to continue the operation once the interrupt has been served. Relying on the software for not altering the interrupt state. The minimal context is saved onto a designed area: often the stack, but dedicated registers or memory are fine too.

Comment: @MargaretBloom AFAIK the processor stores only the address or pointer to the context information , in the stack pointer register. The context information is stored in RAM only ? What do you think ?

Comment: Each processor is different, there is no general answer to your question. Consider that the goal is to resume the interrupt process seamlessly, so everything that can do that is fine. You should pick up an architecture or two and look at their manual, to see some real examples.